# Copy and Pasted Opera's extension JS example, threw errors. Why?

Tags: javascript, opera, opera-extension

**Result**
[image: It's not showing where it's wrong.]

**Question**

This is what's being thrown, but it's not telling me where it is wrong. Given I copied and pasted their example to test that it wasn't just my own extension throwing errors, I would have expected this to work.

I copied this from here:
https://dev.opera.com/extensions/basics/

Why is it breaking?

**Update**

It is now pointing me to errors in my JS that are on lines that do not exist. I would appreciate advice.

**Updated Code**

```
function ReturnInfo(tab) {
    var TitleVal = tab.title;
    var URLVal = tab.url;
    var Dte = new Date();
    var D = Dte.getDate();
    var M = Dte.getMonth();
    var Y = Dte.getFullYear();
    var DateRetrieed = `${D}/${M}/${Y}`;
}

var AllDict = chrome.tabs.getCurrent(ReturnInfo);
```

Comment: share your javascript code. There is syntax error

Comment: Go to the site I linked. As stated, the script was a direct copy and paste. As was the rest of the information.